# What is the meaning of "challenge" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Here is the quote:

> "There is a native trust in the system amongst those who have grown up with it. In contrast, many of the expat community feel that the strategy has neither been communicated clearly nor robustly challenged in the Swedish press. They are deeply worried."

Is it correct to assume "challenged" refers to the noun "strategy" meaning "the strategy was not challenged enough [by the Swedish press]"?

If I'm correct, then what does "to challenge a strategy" mean?

I'd understand if "challenged" referred to "population" like in "to challenge the population to adopt the strategy" (to summon the population to adopt the strategy).

But I can't get the sense of "to challenge a strategy". From this [entry](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/challenge) for "challenge" could it maybe mean "to call for"? Like "the strategy hasn't been robustly called for by the Swedish press"?

Or maybe "to stimulate"? Like "the strategy hasn't been robustly stimulated by the Swedish press"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the second definition in your link: "A demand for explanation or justification; a calling into question"

Comment: In that sense "argued against" would be one way to rephrase it.  It's saying that few people have questioned the merits of the strategy.